# Remove pricing from email templates

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, price, email-templates

My client has a website at "wedowirelessbetter.com" and wants no pricing on any product which I have accomplished already, however when a Pre-Order is sent to a store after a customer checks out, I still see the pricing on the email template.  Is there an easy way to remove this?

I looked at the templates and I see order=$order but removing all of that removes the product from the email and shows nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Andy

Comment: It would help people answer you question if you let them know which template (by file/Magento identifier) you're referring to.  "Pre-Order" is a little too vague.

Answer (score 2):

So order emails have the following line of code that displays items in the order and totals.

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

What this does is that is uses the layout handle `sales_email_order_items` and passes the order `$order` to it.

You can find the layout handle in the file `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml`. You can see that the items are using the following code for rendering.

```
<action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
<action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
```

So the items are rendered via the teample `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml` now what you can do would be to make a copy of this file into your theme and simply remove all the price parts. I think this would be the easiest option for you in this case.